# Angular 5 Testing: Expected to be running in 'ProxyZone', but it was not found

Tags: angular

I have created a new Angular 5 project using Angular cli. When I run the default test, I get the following error:

```
Error: Expected to be running in 'ProxyZone', but it was not found.
at Function.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/proxy.js.ProxyZoneSpec.assertPresent (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/home/sukumar/workspace/bizAnalyst/partnerportal/node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:38:1)
```

How to rectify this issue?

P.S.: Angular version: 5.2.1

Comment: What does your "files" array look like in your karma.conf.js file? It sounds like you're missing a reference to 'node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js'

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I encountered this error message when I accidentally wrote `fakeAsync` into the wrong line:

WRONG:

```
describe('My Test', fakeAsync(() => {
  it('should work', () => {
```

RIGHT:

```
describe('My Test', () => {
  it('should work', fakeAsync(() => {
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice where I placed it

Answer (score 1):

Might possibly in some cases be caused by reduce_vars on uglifyjs... 
in our case with Angular 6 and Webpack 4 (and uglifyjs-webpack-plugin 2.0.1).

Unsure what other contributing factors there might be, just something a colleague found out when trying to narrow a similiar problem down when upgrading to webpack4.

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me if you have a test.ts in your Angular application (given you have not switched to the architect) you must remove

```
import 'zone.js/testing';
```

from test.ts