# How to fix "Error: Expected to be running in 'ProxyZone', but it was not found." in mocha testing?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, mocha.js, mocha-webpack

I am trying to test my Tour of Heroes Angular application using **mocha**, **chai** & **webpack**. I have followed [this post](https://hichambi.github.io/2016/12/27/testing-angular2-with-webpack-mocha-on-browser-and-node.html) & also with the help of [this guide](https://www.radzen.com/blog/testing-angular-webpack-mocha/), have gone through the setup and got the build errors fixed and tests up and running.

But, my tests fails except for the test case where I don't use the `async()` in the `beforeEach` hook.

#### Passing Test

```js
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [HeroService, MessageService]
    });
    httpTestingController = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);

    let mockHeroes = [...mockData];
    let mockHero = mockHeroes[0];
    // let mockId = mockHero.id;

    heroService = TestBed.get(HeroService);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    httpTestingController.verify();
  });

  it('is created', () => {
    expect(heroService).to.exist;
  });
```

---

#### Failing Test

```js
//imports
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
import { HeroSearchComponent } from '../hero-search/hero-search.component';

import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { HeroService } from '../hero.service';
import { expect } from 'chai';

...

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [DashboardComponent, HeroSearchComponent],
      imports: [RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([])],
      providers: [{ provide: HeroService, useValue: heroService }]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DashboardComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(component).to.exist;
  });
```

---

#### Error Stack Trace

> 1. DashboardComponent
>
> > ```
> >   "before each" hook for "should be created":
> > ```
>
> ```
> Error: Expected to be running in 'ProxyZone', but it was not found.
>  at Function.ProxyZoneSpec.assertPresent (node_modules\zone.js\dist\proxy.js:42:19)
>  at runInTestZone (node_modules\zone.js\dist\async-test.js:202:23)
>  at D:\Practice\Tour-Of-Heroes\node_modules\zone.js\dist\async-test.js:185:17
>  at new ZoneAwarePromise (node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:910:29)
>  at Context.<anonymous> (node_modules\zone.js\dist\async-test.js:184:20)
> ```

I have tried [Angular 5 Testing: Expected to be running in 'ProxyZone', but it was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48789782/8947616) as I thought this was some error with *zone.js* using **mocha**, but without success.

Also, I have tried following [Mocha Documentation](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code) for asynchronous testing, but as a beginner, it was somewhat hard for me.

I have tried googling and even in Stack Overflow, but there are only a limited amount of posts regarding Angular testing with mocha.
Any help getting through this is appreciated.

Comment: 5th Angular specific error I've hit today. This framework is such a timesink.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I had the same issue when accidentally using `fakeAsync` in a `describe` function.

Removed it solved the issue for me.

Comment: This was my problem. I put the fackAsync() around my describe() function by accident instead of around the it() function.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the answer to this question.

[Angular 5 Testing: Expected to be running in 'ProxyZone', but it was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48789782/angular-5-testing-expected-to-be-running-in-proxyzone-but-it-was-not-found/50389299)

Basically this exception is coming because of the incorrect position of an async keyword. Remove the async from beforeEach and add it on "it"

```
it('should be created', fakeAsync(() => {
    expect(component).to.exist;
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

2021

Adding the line below as first import to the spec file fixed this problem for me:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';
```

Comment: With `zone.js` `0.14` use `import 'zone.js/testing';` instead !

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the solution was to add `"target": "ES2016"` in the `tsconfig.spec.json` file.

Indeed, after migrating my app to Angular 15, I set `"target": "ES2022"` in the main `tsconfig.json` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75093294/12292636)).
But it raises [a well-known issue](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/21632#issuecomment-764975917) in the tests using `async`/`await` syntax.

Credits to: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/15577#issuecomment-1465737796

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and removing `async` from `beforeEach` (and `it`) solved the problem. The error message is not helpful at all, but I guess is not easy from where it is generated to detect what the root cause is.

Comment: Ya the problem is I needed to test for asynchronous code and removing async is not an option when coming to that part.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues here.

You have 2 beforeEach. You should only have 1.
If you have async on your block of test code, then you need to call await on a function, and/or use flush or tick to progress time.
I usually use fakeAsync for observables, and async/await for real async methods.

For this specific example, you shouldn't need the async at all.

Comment: Having multiple beforeEach is ok in Karma/Jasmine tests. Also, as `compileComponents` returns a promise, OP needs the `await` in there, or use `waitForAsync`

Answer (score 0):

with angular 14 we added imports (to fix our jest setup) to

```
  require('zone.js');
  require('zone.js/testing');
```

in our jest setupFilesAfterEnv file
however when running with ng test those imports are alreaddy done by angular resulting in duplicate imports and conflicts resulting in the above error

the solutions then was to wrap the imports in a condition:

```
if (!('Zone' in global)){
  require('zone.js');
  require('zone.js/testing');
}
```