# zone.js expected to be running in ProxyZone

Tags: angular, zone.js

I feel like this has been asked many times, but none of the solutions I find is helping and I'm a bit lost what is the cause of my issue. The solutions usually suggest that either the async/fakeAsync call was set in the wrong place (e.g. describe instead of beforeEach) or to remove the async completely but non of that is working and as this is a plain generated test I would expect it to just run.

So, no matter what test case I want to run I'm facing the following issue:

```
Error: Expected to be running in 'ProxyZone', but it was not found.
        at Function.assertPresent (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:215:23)
        at Object.resetFakeAsyncZone (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:1997:54)
        at resetFakeAsyncZone (packages/core/testing/src/fake_async.ts:23:32)
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (packages/core/testing/src/before_each.ts:26:5)
        at <Jasmine>
```

I tried that with a completely empty and freshly generated component, where the test case is auto generated by the cli and it fails as well. Here is the test-case component test:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { TestCaseComponent } from './test-case.component';

describe('TestCaseComponent', () => {
   let component: TestCaseComponent;
   let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestCaseComponent>;

beforeEach(async () => {
   await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ TestCaseComponent ]
 })
.compileComponents();
});

beforeEach(() => {
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestCaseComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;
fixture.detectChanges();
});

 it('should create', () => {
 expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I run the test with the following command:

> ng test --include=**/test-case.component.spec.ts

I'm using the zone.js version 0.11.4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "Error: Expected to be running in 'ProxyZone', but it was not found." in mocha testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56034177/how-to-fix-error-expected-to-be-running-in-proxyzone-but-it-was-not-found)

Answer (score 2):

Well just that I posted my question here I figured it out...
During one of the several attempts to solve the issue I added this line

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js'
```

to my pollyfills.ts file.

However it seems not to be needed here and has to be added at the very beginning of the test.ts file.