# How to fix "Argument for '--target' option must be: 'es3', 'es5', 'es6', 'es2015', 'es2016', 'es2017', 'es2018', 'es2019', 'es2020', 'es201', 'esnext'

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio

I cloned an Angular application and I'm getting the below error for the "target" property in the tsconfig.json file in Visual Studio 2019. I am currently running on Angular v16.1.4, and Typescript v5.1.6. I'm also wondering if fixing this error will fix the remaining errors in the solution?

I've tried updating the "target" property to the other versions of ES but I'm still getting the error. Anyone know how to resolve this issue?

[image]

Per this question [Typescript target warnings after Angular 15 update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75047760/typescript-target-warnings-after-angular-15-update), there was a GitHub issue created https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/25290.

Comment: Not sure if this will help ... but something I've done in cases like this is to create a new project so it has all of the correct bootstrapping files. I use the Angular CLI (I haven't used Visual Studio for Angular development but the Visual Studio Angular template may work for this as well.) Then I replace the app folder with the folder from the original project. Worth a try?

Comment: what if you try opening that Angular project with VSCode? I have the exact value `ES2022` for `target` in a real project application that I'm working on, I personally don't use Visual Studio for frontend development

Answer (score 0):

1- Update node version "ES2022" is only supported greater or node version 18x

**Command to update node:**

Installing the Node Version Manager:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.3/install.sh | bash
```

Once you have Node Version Manager installed do the following:

Run in your terminal `nvm install 18` to install version 18 of Node.
Run `nvm use 18` to start using version 18 of Node.

Then run `npm update` on your `Angular` application.