Opt-out of Angular v16 overriding TypeScript target to ES2022
I realized that Angular CLI overrides tsconfig target property to ES2022. I want to opt-out that because my tsconfig target is set to ES2020. I must give support to Chrome v90 browsers. Is it possible, if so how?
I created a browserslist file with the browser versions that I target. That did not work either.

Is it causing any issue if the target is set to ES2022? If not, you can set it to ES2022 in the tsconfig.json file.

@SMVaidhyanathan yes, some of our clients report errors. in the console there are 2 unexpected token errors. so, its not an option to upgrade to ES2022

Ok. This answer might be helpful. Check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76369523/10793665

Chrome v90 is heavily outdated (released in April 2021) and is not supported by Angular 16 (released in May 2023). Only the last 2 chrome versions are supported, see the docs.
